# Why memory leaks with a dynamic array of a custom class?

Tags: mql4, mql5

I'm creating a indicator that recognizes candlestick shapes.

To do that I created a separate **`class Candlestick`** that I include to the indicator file.

The problem is that I suffer from memory leaks.

I'm new to pointers and after reading / watching a lot, I still seem to miss something here.

This is the Indicator class. The content of the `Candlestick` class is irrelevant so I leave that out.

```
Candlestick *candles[]; 

void OnDeinit(const int reason)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < ArraySize(candles); i++ ){
      delete(candles[i]);
    }
}

int OnCalculate(args here)
{
    ArrayResize(candles, Bars);

    for(int i = MathMax(Bars-2-IndicatorCounted(), 1); i >= 0; i--)
    {            
        candles[i] = new Candlestick();

        // Do stuff with this candle (and other candles) here e.g.
        if(candles[i+1].type == BULLISH) Print("Last candle was Bullish");
    }
}
```

When I do this I get memory leak errors. It seems that I need to delete the pointers to the candles in that dynamic array. The problem is, **when** and **where?** Because I need them in the next iteration of the **`for(){...}`** loop. So I can't delete it there.

When I delete it in the `OnDeinit()` function there are still candles out there and I still get the leak error.

How come?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, Nick, welcome to the **Worlds of `MQL4`**

You might have already realised, the **`MQL4`** code is not a **`C`**.

Among many important differences, the key here is what does the code-execution platform ( the <kbd>MetaTrader Terminal 4</kbd> ) do in what moment.

**`OnCalculate()`** is a zombie-alike process, which **gets invoked many times**, but anyway, **definitely not under your control**.

Next, `OnCalculate()` by-design does not mean a new `Bar`.

---

### How to?

`MQL4` conceptually originates from days, when computing resources were many orders smaller and much more expensive in terms of their time-sharing CPU-MUX-ing during a code execution phase.

Thus the `MQL4`-user-domain language retains benefits from some hidden gems, that are not accessible directly. One of these is a very efficient register-based update-processing and keeping dynamic resources allocations on miminum, for their devastatingly adverse effects on Real-Time execution predictability.

This will help you understand how to design & handle your conceptual objects way smarter, best by mimicking this ***"stone-age"*-but-VERY-efficient** behaviour ( both time-wise & memory-wise ), instead of flooding your memory-pool with infinite amount of unmanaged instances upon each call of `OnCalulate()` which sprinkles an endless count of **`new Candlestick(); // *--> candles[]`**

---

### A best next step:

If in doubts, just read about best practices for **`ArrayResize()`** in the platform localhost-help/documentation, to start realise the things, that introduce overheads ( if not blocks ) in a domain, where `nano$econd$` count & hurt in professional software design.

Comment: After asking this question last night, I went to bed and was thinking: "Did I put this code in the wrong place?". I think your answer is in line with that. Correct?

Comment: I also noticed that `MQL4` shifts the latest Bar up when a new Bar is created. (0 -> 1). I need to mimic this behavior.
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I got it working now. I removed everything except `ArrayResize(candles, Bars)` from `OnCalculate()`. Now, in `OnInit()` I call `ArraySetAsSeries(candles, true)` and also `ArrayRezise(candles, Bars)` after that. I changed the code in the `DeInit()` so that it deletes all Candlestick pointers in the array when done. Hooray.. ! Again thanks a lot for pointing me out. Better then just pasting an example. I actually learn from t his :). I made a [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/Aelt3dj.png) of the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks, @Nique Also do read carefully about array-sizing memory pre-allocations, a must read if latency matters. Could handle more than a few hundreds thousands records ( as a **`db.Pool()` DMA-cache** -- a thing that would kill `OrderSelect()` and other standard `db.Pool()` operations in [_StrategyTester_] in HFT-strategies )

Comment: Plus a minor note, all [_Custom Indicator_]-s together are sharing one **single thread**, so be very carefull about any latency, the more any potential blocking if going into a distributed processing ( and rather forget about **file-I/O, which always blocks** about a few tens of milliseconds ).

Comment: I will dive in to that. At the moment my indicator is very simple and won't perform orders. It's just to analyze the Bars and recognize patterns. No auto-ordering stuff. But I think it is good to learn about the latency stuff. When I only turn on the (build-in) Bollingerbands indicator the countdown  timer seems to lag already. (believe me, i got superb internet and a beast of a computer, so it's not my computer. I think something is wrong with the indicator. But this is a whole other topic.

Comment: FYI: Custom Indicator is explicitly forbidden to submit orders ( due to the above mentioned performance bottleneck + synchronous-service-alike blocking of the undivisible localhost transaction-processing till a dual transport & server-side processing latencies take place)